# Cant get Multiple Nodes in AEM 6.1

Tags: content-management-system, aem

We have recently upgraded from AEM 5.6.1 to AEM 6.1 and our certain piece code given below has suddenly stopped working. In brief, we have been using the Node API to get child nodes of a particular node and then processing on it, but in AEM 6.1, it seems getNodes() method returns nothing and only getNode() seem to work. Has anyone else also faced the same and have any solution for it?

```
if (jobAdNode.hasNode(PARSYS_NODE_REL_PATH)) {
            Node parsysNode = jobAdNode.getNode(PARSYS_NODE_REL_PATH);
            NodeIterator textNodeItr = parsysNode.getNodes("text"); // RETURNS NOTHING
            Node textNode1 = parsysNode.getNode("text"); // RETURN THE EXISTING TEXT NODE
            if (textNodeItr.getSize() > 0) {
                Node textNode = textNodeItr.nextNode();
                if (textNode.hasProperty(TEXT_PROP)) {
                    resDescription.append(textNode.getProperty(TEXT_PROP).getString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of hit and trials, I have located the issue and would like to post here, in case anyone else faces the same. In the code that I posted above, the culprit is this line:

```
if (textNodeItr.getSize() > 0)
```

The parsysNode.getNodes("text"), method returns an iterator of nodes having the child nodes, however the getSize method still returns -1 and hence it looks like that no nodes are being returned. Look at the documentation of getSize() method [here](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/RangeIterator.html#getSize())! , which says that the getSize method may not return the size in all implementations.

I solved the issue by using hasNext() which is mostly used.